# vertical scrollerbar always visible in vaadin 8 grid

Tags: vaadin, vaadin8, vaadin-grid

I would like to make vertical scrollerbar always visible in vaadin 8 grid.
Why? Because if vertical scrollerbar appears, the columns move a bit to make space for vertical scrollerbar. So I would like vertical scrollerbar to stay always visible so that columns will always be in the same position.
I have tried variation of, but can not make it work:

in java:

```
ordersGridDetail.addStyleName("gridAlwaysScrollbar");
```

in scss:

```
.gridAlwaysScrollbar .v-grid {
    .v-grid-scroller-vertical {
        overflow-y: scroll !important; 
    }
}
```

There is some info on https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/10624506/10679832 but I have no success.

Answer (score 0):

Grid has some internal (rather complex) JavaScript logic, which dynamically adds/removes the scroll bar depending on the condition. Thus you cannot override that behavior with CSS.

Comment: Is there any other way to do it, some property I can set or something ? Thanks